# The algorithm for synchronizing between WaitForSingleObject() and SetEvent() functions?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I want to implement a message queue for 2 threads. Thread #1 will pop the messages in queue and process it. Thread #2 will push the messages into queue.

Here is my code:

```
 Thread #1 //Pop message and process
 {
    while(true)
    {
        Lock(mutex);
        message = messageQueue.Pop();
        Unlock(mutex);

        if (message == NULL) //the queue is empty
        {
           //assume that the interruption occurs here (*)
            WaitForSingleObject(hWakeUpEvent, INFINITE);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            //process message
        }
    }
}

Thread #2 //push  new message in queue and wake up thread #1
{
    Lock(mutex);
    messageQueue.Push(newMessage)
    Unlock(mutex);

    SetEvent(hWakeUpEvent);
}
```

The problem is there are some cases `SetEvent(hWakeUpEvent)` will be called before `WaitForSingleObject()` ( note (*) ), it will be dangerous.

Comment: Search for concurrent bounded queue. It will simply your problem.

Comment: What do you mean "it will be dangerous"?

Comment: I think what you describe is not a problem, because if SetEvent is called first, WaitForSingleObject will not sleep at all but rather return immediately, so that your loop continues with its next iteration. See msdn "The state of a manual-reset event object remains signaled until it is set explicitly to the nonsignaled state by the ResetEvent function. Any number of waiting threads, or threads that subsequently begin wait operations for the specified event object by calling one of the wait functions, can be released while the object's state is signaled."

Comment: @Tudor: I mean that if SetEvent(hWakeUpEvent) will be called before WaitForSingleObject(). It may make the thread #1 wait forever.

Comment: @TTGroup: Not really. The Event will remain signaled until you call `ResetEvent`. It is not lost if "nobody is listening".

Comment: @TTGroup Is your event manual reset, or auto reset? To the best of my knowledge, you need to use manual reset.

Comment: Yes, what others have said.  SetEvent() sets the event to signaled and it stays set until you manually call ResetEvent() (in the case of non-auto-resetting events) or a waiting thread is released (in the case of auto-resetting events).  Either way, `WaitForSingleObject()` will still return to allow processing to continue when you get to it.

Comment: A better question is what happens if thread #1 is interrupted right before you call `Unlock(mutex)`...

Comment: Manual or automatic doesn't matter, @David. As long as you don't use `PulseEvent`, the event will remain signaled until someone waits for it. Given the code here, the event needs to be an auto-reset event since nothing ever calls `ResetEvent`.

Comment: @rob thanks, I remember reading tails of woe with events and I think you are right that PulseEvent is the thing that doesn't work.

Comment: @All: Thanks all, Now I have really understood how to these functions work by reading your all explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine!

There's no actual problem with timing between SetEvent and WaitForSingleObject: the key issue is that WaitForSingleObject on an event will check the state of the event, and wait until it is triggered. If the event is already triggered, it will return immediately. (In technical terms, it's level-triggered, not edge-triggered.) This means that it's fine if SetEvent is called either before or during the call to WaitForSingleObject; WaitForSingleObject will return in either case; either immediately or when SetEvent is called later on.

(BTW, I'm assuming using an Automatic Reset event here. I can't think of a good reason for using a Manual Reset event; you'd just end up having to call ResetEvent immediately after WaitForSingleObject returns; and there's a danger that if your forget this, you could end up Waiting for an event you've already waited for but forgotten to clear. Additionally,it's important to Reset before checking the underlying data state, otherwise if SetEvent is called between when the data is processed and Reset() is called, you lose that information. Stick with Automatic Reset, and you avoid all this.)

--

[Edit: I misread the OP's code as doing a single 'pop' on each wake, rather than only waiting on empty, so the comments below refer to code that scenario. The OP's code is actually equivalent to the second suggested fix below. So the text below is really describing a somewhat common coding error where events are used as through they were semaphores, rather than the OP's actual code.]

But there is a different problem here [or, there would be if there was only one pop per wait...], and that's that Win32 Events objects have only two states: unsignaled and signaled, so you can use them only to track binary state, but not to count. If you SetEvent and event that's already signaled, it remains Signaled, and the information of that extra SetEvent call is lost.

In that case, what could happen is:

- Item is added, SetEvent called, event is now signaled.
- Another item is added, SetEvent is called again, event stays signaled.
- Worker thread calls WaitForSingleObject, which returns, clearing the event,
- only one item is processed,
- worker thread calls WaitForsingleObject, which blocks because the event is unsignaled, even though there's still an item in the queue.

There's two ways around this: the classic Comp.Sci way is to use a semaphore instead of an event - semaphores are essentially events that count up all the 'Set' calls; you could conversely think of an event as a semaphore with a max count of 1 which ignores any other signals beyond that one.

An alternative way is to continue using events, but when the worker thread wakes up, it can only assume that there may be *some* items in the queue, and it should attempt to process them all before it returns to waiting - typically by putting the code that pops the item in a loop that pops items and processes them until its empty. The event is now used not to count, but rather to signal "the queue is no longer empty". (Note that when you do this, you can also get cases where, while processing the queue, you also process an item that was just added and for which SetEvent was called, so that when the worker thread reaches WaitForSingleObject, the thread wakes up but finds the queue is empty as the item has already been processed; this can seem a bit surprising at first, but is actually fine.)

I view these two as mostly equivalent; there's minor pros and cons to both, but they're both correct. (Personally I prefer the events approach, since it decouples the concept of "something needing to be done" or "more data is available" from the quantity of that work or data.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Your explanation is very clearly. Two above ways you raised are good ways. In my above code have checked the queue in empty state before calling WaitForSingleObject(), so i think it worked correctly.

Comment: I concur that the loop as written does not suffer from the problem described, because it only waits for the event after it observes that the message queue is empty. Still, the explanation of a potential pitfall and how to avoid it is good.

Comment: @Vincent Povirk: Thank you, but I don't see any "potential pitfall" in above code. Can you show me that case? Thanks again.

Comment: @TTGroup: *slaps head* - yup, you're right; I'm used to seeing the pattern as a loop-till-empty-within-infinite-loop, so missed the fact that your code is equivalent ( - that's what I get for answering SO late at night!). I'll edit my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks, you are great, BrendanMcK ^^

Answer (score 2):

The 'classic' way, (ie. will surely work correctly), is to use a semaphore, (see CreateSemaphore, ReleaseSemaphore API).  Create the semaphore empty.  In the producer thread, lock the mutex, push the message, unlock the mutex, release a unit to the semaphore.  In the consumer thread, wait on the semaphore handle with WFSO, (like you wait on the event above), then lock the mutex, pop a message, unlock the mutex.

Why is this better than events?

1) No need to check the queue count - the semaphore counts the messages.

2) A signal to the semaphore is not 'lost' just because no thread is waiting on it.

3) Not checking the queue count means that result from, and code path taken as a result of, such checking cannot be incorrect because of preemption.

4) It will work for multiple producers and multiple consumers without change.

5) It is more cross-platform friendly - all preemptive OS have mutexes/semaphores.

Comment: Thank you, i think it will be the good way to apply in this case. But I may keep my above code for simple ^.^

Comment: +1 - though note that (2) also applies to events; so long as you use SetEvent rather than PulseEvent, event signals are also not lost because that no thread is waiting on it.

Comment: @BrendanMcK - yes, events are lost. Signal an empty semaphore once, it's count becomes 1.  Signal an empty semaphore 100 times, it's count becomes 100.  Event - no matter how many times you signal it, it just stays set - it has no count.

Comment: @MartinJames: got it; I mis-understood the point your were making; perhaps the problem is that the wording in your answer is somewhat ambiguous: the issue there is that events are not *counted*; but if you signal an unsignalled event while no thread is waiting, that first signal is not lost (though it's still not counted, so *additional* signals are lost). It might be useful to edit the (2) answer to mention counting explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be dangerous if there were several threads consuming data at the same time, or if you used `PulseEvent` instead of `SetEvent`.

But with only one consumer, and since the event will be kept signaled until you wait into it (if auto rest) or forever (if manual reset), it should just work.